# How often are the stats on the SE.com sites list updated?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, statistics, stackexchange.com

I am a moderator on [WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) and we are working hard to improve our answer rate. The [statistics page on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) is currently the only way to *see* the current number. Of course, one can just calculate the answer ratio with the total number of questions and the number of unanswered questions. But that’s not very user friendly.
We want to give some visual feedback to our members who are helping actively cleaning up  old questions.

It seems the statistics page is not updated very often. I think each Saturday, but I’m not sure.

How often is this page updated? Is there a public graph somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statistics on the [stackexchange.com sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) are updated at least daily.

The "% answered" stat, in particular, is updated every 3 hours. You can always derive the value yourself by hitting https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/info?site=wordpress and then calculating

```
100 * (total_questions - total_unanswered) / total_questions
```